# SQL JOIN issue - complex SELECT as JOIN Condition

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select, join, key

I'm trying to join two tables that have character keys and I need to use a SELECT query to form one of the join conditions. Here is the data:

```
Table M

MKey OtherData
---- ---------
ABCD kjjh
EFGH oioo
IJKL uhdjdhu
MNOP isdid
QRST lkuh

Table FUN

FUNKey  BinaryField
------  -----------
ABCD/GGG 1
ABCD/KKK 0
ABCD/MMM 1
EFGH/ABC 1
IJKL/DDD 1
IJKL/VVV 1
IJKL/XXX 0
MNOP/AAA 1
NMOP/DEF 1
NMOP/FFF 1
QRST/SSS 0
```

There are no unique or numeric fields in either table and no other fields they can be JOINed on.

This is my starting query with the JOIN:

```
Select MKey,Otherdata from M
LEFT OUTER JOIN FUN
ON M.MKey = left(FUNKey, CHARINDEX ('/', FUNKey) -1)
AND FUN.BinaryData=1

Returns

ABCD kjjh
ABCD kjjh
EFGH oioo
IJKL uhdjdhu
ABCD kjjh
MNOP isdid
MNOP isdid
MNOP isdid
MNOP isdid
```

What I need it to return is one row from M where there is one of more rows in FUN that begin with "MKey" and have FUN.BinaryData=1, like this:

```
ABCD kjjh
EFGH oioo
IJKL uhdjdhu
MNOP isdid
```

I've tried GROUP BY, MIN, MAX on the FUN.FUNKey column with no success.

If I use a query that uses ROW_NUMBER, OVER, and PARTITION etc. on its own I get what I want to join on:

```
(Select M_Code from

(Select left(F.FUNKey, CHARINDEX ('/', F.FUNKey) -1) as M_Code
,row_number () over (partition by left(F.FUNKey, CHARINDEX ('/', F.FUNKey) -1) 
order by left(F.FUNKey, CHARINDEX ('/', F.FUNKey) -1))

as rn
from FUN F
where F.BinaryData=1
) tmp

Where rn=1
)
```

Returns:

```
ABCD
EFGH
IJKL
MNOP
```

So I think I'm good until I try to use it for the join:

```
The following code gives me:
"Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an
expression."

Select MKey,Otherdata from M
LEFT OUTER JOIN ON M.MKEY = 

(Select M_Code from

(Select left(F.FUNKey, CHARINDEX ('/', F.FUNKey) -1) as M_Code
,row_number () over (partition by left(F.FUNKey, CHARINDEX ('/', F.FUNKey) -1) 
order by left(F.FUNKey, CHARINDEX ('/', F.FUNKey) -1))

as rn
from FUN F
where F.BinaryData=1
) tmp

Where rn=1
)
```

Is there a simple solution to using the results of a SELECT in a join that I'm missing or am I trying to divide by zero (again)?

Environment is MS SQL 20012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit unclear what it is you want to accomplish but maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT MKey, Otherdata 
FROM M
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT 
      LEFT(FUNKey, CHARINDEX ('/', FUNKey) -1) FUNKEY
    , BinaryData 
    FROM FUN
) F ON M.MKey = F.FUNKEY AND F.BinaryData = 1;
```

This would return:

```
MKey                 Otherdata
-------------------- --------------------
ABCD                 kjjh
EFGH                 oioo
IJKL                 uhdjdhu
MNOP                 isdid
QRST                 lkuh
```

If you don't want the last row (which has BinaryData = 0) then change the AND in the join condition to WHERE instead.

Comment: but in result set he is not showing for QRST, lkuh @jpw

Comment: @Jonathan I realize that which was why I addressed it in the last sentence. I assumed that the OP wanted that row as the original query used a `left outer join` Otherwise an `inner join` would have maed more sense.

Comment: I agreed forgot to see @jpw

Comment: @jpw That works! Simple and effective. I did move F.BinaryData=1 to behind a WHERE (there were actually two binary fields in FUN I needed to test). Thanks for the prompt and accurate answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @Table1 TABLE 
    ([MKey] varchar(4), [OtherData] varchar(7))
;

INSERT INTO @Table1
    ([MKey], [OtherData])
VALUES
    ('ABCD', 'kjjh'),
    ('EFGH', 'oioo'),
    ('IJKL', 'uhdjdhu'),
    ('MNOP', 'isdid'),
    ('QRST', 'lkuh')
;
declare @Table2 TABLE 
    ([FUNKey] varchar(8), [BinaryField] int)
;

INSERT INTO @Table2
    ([FUNKey], [BinaryField])
VALUES
    ('ABCD/GGG', 1),
    ('ABCD/KKK', 0),
    ('ABCD/MMM', 1),
    ('EFGH/ABC', 1),
    ('IJKL/DDD', 1),
    ('IJKL/VVV', 1),
    ('IJKL/XXX', 0),
    ('MNOP/AAA', 1),
    ('NMOP/DEF', 1),
    ('NMOP/FFF', 1),
    ('QRST/SSS', 0)

;
;with CTE AS(
select A.MKey,
      A.OtherData,
      BinaryField,
ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY OtherData ORDER BY (SELECT NULL) )RN from (
Select MKey,Otherdata,BinaryField  
 from @Table1 M
       LEFT OUTER JOIN @Table2 FUN
 ON M.MKey = left(FUNKey, CHARINDEX ('/', FUNKey) -1)
AND FUN.BinaryField=1)A )
Select MKey,
       OtherData
 from CTE 
where RN = 1 
AND BinaryField IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY Mkey
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you all are making this harder than it is

```
Select distinct M.MKey, M.Otherdata 
from M
JOIN FUN
     ON M.MKey = left(FUNKey, CHARINDEX ('/', FUNKey) -1)
     AND FUN.BinaryData = 1
```